# 12V @ 1A from a 6V to 20V input

Tags: power-supply, sepic

I have a 6V to 20V input I want to convert to 12V at 1 amp maximum continuous current. The output must be the same polarity as the input, so that pretty much means a SEPIC is the only way to go... However, I've been looking around and all solutions I've seen thus far require many components and a lot of surface area; I'm looking to minimise surface area as far as possible, and to do this I don't mind sacrificing a bit of efficiency. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Have you look at buck-boost ICs?

Comment: can you put numbers to things like "minimize surface area"? what kind of range would you consider acceptable?

Comment: A buck boost would invert polarity.

Comment: I'm looking for <250mm^2 area.

Comment: A buck stage (reducing the input to 4V) followed by a boost stage (4V to 12V) would not invert polarity. Efficiency wouldn't be great (cascaded converters) but it would do the job.

Comment: Yeah, but then I have to have a buck converter rated to deliver 3 amps (+inefficiencies) instead of a SEPIC at 1 amp. A 3 amp buck converter could be quite big, possibly bigger than the SEPIC itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Page 31 of [this datasheet](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/3757Afd.pdf) for the Linear Technology LT3757 has an application circuit using a SEPIC converter for a 5.5v to 36v input and 12v 2A output.  The biggest part appears to be the [dual inductor](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/DRQ127-4R7-R/513-1147-1-ND/754645), which is 12.5 mm square.  Since you only need a 1A output, you might get by with a smaller inductor in the [DRQ74](http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Detail&name=513-1263-1-ND) series, which is 7.6 mm square, however it is currently a non-stock item at Digi-Key.

Comment: Nooo, the link is broken.

Comment: @sherrellbc Links fixed.  I answered this 3 1/2 years ago, have no idea how long they've been broken.

Comment: Wow, I certainly was not expecting any reply to that. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I've built a SEPIC and published this page about it, there's even a description of how to build a the inductor without unobtainium:
http://dren.dk/carpower.html

... but the inductor design is pretty hackish, so it's not going to win any medals for production use.